# Internet Explorer child window in VBA

Tags: vba, childwindow

I have  a VBA code that clicks a link on a IE page and a new window opens. How can I get the elements of that child window?

I tried with Shell.application. Are there any other methods?

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
IEcount= objShell.Windows.Count
 For x = 0 To iecount
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print x, objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
 Next x
```

I got the window number and its URL but can't access the elements on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "if-then" statement I've inserted within your code. You can use either the title or url to identify the child and set focus on it.  Once it has focus, you can get the elements of the child window.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    If my_title Like "Something that identifies your child window" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The title of the child window is the same as in the parent window. I found the child page url, but when I activate objShell.Windows(x) nothing happens. I tried it with objShell.Windows(x).activate and also with appActivate. What am I missing?

Comment: what's the website, then I can troubleshoot

Comment: it's a company intranet

Comment: When the Set ie = objShell.Windows(x) is triggered, (x) is correct, the macro successfully steps through the "Set IE" line, exits the "for" loop, but the macro is not interacting with the child page?  Maybe open a third page and see if the macro runs correctly if you have it set to focus on this third web page

Comment: The objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location part was the wrong one. Even if it returned the correct URL, when activating the window, it activated something else. I changed  objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location with objShell.Windows(x).LocationURL and now it works perfectly. Thank you for your help Ron